# c++ structs & method , NOT RETURNING CORRECTLY

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, struct, return

I have a subroutine `Map build(Map the_map)` being called to update my variable `new_map` and the map is being updated INSIDE THE SUBROUTINE but when it returns it returns the same map UN-UPDATED, 

note:

I tested with `cout` statements inside the method and also after the method is returned to the switch...

Here is a snippet of my code: 

1 the struct details

2 and the moment where the subroutine is being called

3 and subroutine code


Structs

```
struct MapItem {    
    char type = 'E';    
};

struct Map {
    int size = 0;
    MapItem *items;
};
```

Subroutine called in switch (if user selects build option) build on map

```
case BUILD:
                new_map = build(new_map);
                break;
```

Subroutine

```
Map build (Map the_map) {

    char building_code;
    int coordinate_x;
    int coordinate_y;
    int build_location;

    cout << "Enter x and y coordinate: ";
    cin  >> coordinate_x;
    cin  >> coordinate_y;

    build_location = (coordinate_x+(coordinate_y*the_map.size));

    cout << "Enter a building code: ";
    cin >> building_code;

    the_map.items[build_location].type = building_code;

    return the_map;
}
```

Comment: You are returning a `Map` by value, but we have no idea if your `Map` class has correct copy semantics (the rule of 3).  Where is your user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor for `Map`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: There is no difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C++ except for default access specification and derivation.  So my comment still stands -- you must have the "big 3" for your `Map` to be safely copyable.

Comment: so when the instance of Map is passed to the subroutine , it is being copied ? 

okay ill give the big 3 a try .

but ALSO i have another method that updates the size of a Map object and it doesn't have the same issue and im calling it the same way . 
new_map = create_new_game (Map the_map);
it updates the size of the map and returns the map. but it must have something to do with the semantics again.

thanks

Comment: It is being copied using the default copy constructor.  The default is *not* adequate, as you have a member that is a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.  All you will be doing is making a "shallow" copy, which does not do the job.  That is what the "rule of 3" is all about -- I suggest you read it as it is the reason you are having issues with your program.

Comment: If you are copying your `Map` object as-is in any way now, it is wrong.  It doesn't matter if the error is not visible to you.  You're going to have double `delete` errors as well as memory leaks.  Also, at the link, go to the *Managing Resources* section.  The example there is almost verbatim to your `Map` class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ... or if s/he has none of them. In this case the class is not exception-safe (since it doesn't free its owned resources) but should otherwise be okay.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Why isn't the default copy constructor sufficient? If allocation of MapItems are handle elsewhere in the code, I don't see a problem with that part. It is not a good idea to pass by value here but still I don't see the problems you mention (e.g. double delete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the map by reference instead.

Like this:

```
void build (Map& the_map) {

    char building_code;
    int coordinate_x;
    int coordinate_y;
    int build_location;

    cout << "Enter x and y coordinate: ";
    cin  >> coordinate_x;
    cin  >> coordinate_y;

    build_location = (coordinate_x+(coordinate_y*the_map.size));

    cout << "Enter a building code: ";
    cin >> building_code;

    the_map.items[build_location].type = building_code;
}
```

and

```
case BUILD:
                build(new_map);
                break;
```

When you pass by reference you can alter the variable (i.e. map) directly and you avoid all the copying complexity.

BTW: I assume you have already reserved memory for MapItems somewhere else in your code but you probably need some range check inside your build-function so that you don't write outside the allocated memory.

If you have initialized things correctly your initial code should be fine. I tried it like this:

```
    Map build(Map the_map) {

    char building_code;
    int coordinate_x;
    int coordinate_y;
    int build_location;

    cout << "Enter x and y coordinate: ";
    cin >> coordinate_x;
    cin >> coordinate_y;

    build_location = (coordinate_x + (coordinate_y*the_map.size));

    // Range check
    if ((build_location >= (the_map.size*the_map.size)) || (build_location < 0))
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
        return the_map;
    }

    cout << "Enter a building code: ";
    cin >> building_code;

    the_map.items[build_location].type = building_code;

    return the_map;
}


int main()
{
    // Just a const so that map size can be change here
    const int mapSize = 3;

    // Create the map
    Map new_map;

    // Initialize map size
    new_map.size = mapSize;

    // Allocate memory for the MapItems
    new_map.items = new MapItem[mapSize * mapSize];

    // Do some simple test...
    for (int i = 0; i < mapSize * mapSize; i++) cout << new_map.items[i].type << " ";
    cout << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        new_map = build(new_map);
        for (int i = 0; i < mapSize * mapSize; i++) cout << new_map.items[i].type << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Deallocate memory
    delete[] new_map.items;

    return 0;
}


E E E E E E E E E
Enter x and y coordinate: 2 0
Enter a building code: Y
E E Y E E E E E E
Enter x and y coordinate: 0 2
Enter a building code: Z
E E Y E E E Z E E
Enter x and y coordinate: 2 2
Enter a building code: P
E E Y E E E Z E P
```

But I'll recommend the pass-by-referance instead.

Comment: hey thanks, yeah i started changing my methods to get a value by reference, and was struggling trying to access the elements , but i see how you did it here : >>>> " new_map.items = new MapItem[mapSize * mapSize]; " 

this really helps thanks!!!

Comment: hey so, ive finished the entire program but its giving me one error when i try to call delete [] every time i create a map greater or equal to 25 it just hangs the program gets to the delete [] array because when comment the delete statement out the program can exit even if i create an array larger or equal to 25

Comment: It works fine for me. For debug try to remove everything between `new_map.items = new MapItem[mapSize * mapSize];` and `delete[] new_map.items;`.

Comment: what i had to do was make a new method , and send it the map to delete .... i dont really get what was going on there. --------------------------invoking delete_map(new_map)  -----------------implementing
void delete_map (Map map){
 delete [] map.items;
}